# Pandas bitwise comparisons throws exception when using multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a large data, and I want to extract a subset. 
In SQL representation this is what I want to achieve. I would like to do this using pandas/numpy.

```
select * from Data where cpty_type = 'INTERBRANCH' and (settlementDate >= '2017-04-18 00:00:00.000' or settlementDate = '1899-12-30 00:00:00.000'))
```

These two statements on their own work:

```
#1.  unionX1 = data[data.cpty_type == 'INTERBRANCH']
#2.  unionX1 = data[data.settlementDate >= '2017-04-18 00:00:00.000']
```

My versions (combining both does not work):

```
unionX1 = data[data.cpty_type == 'INTERBRANCH' & (data.settlementDate >= '2017-04-18' | data.settlementDate == '2017-04-18')]
```

I get the following exception when I run it:
**I think it is cause by the bit-wise comparison**
Any suggestion on what I am doing wrong here?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 877, in na_op
    result = op(x, y)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 127, in <lambda>
    ror_=bool_method(lambda x, y: operator.or_(y, x),
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_or' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 895, in na_op
        result = lib.scalar_binop(x, y, op)
      File "pandas\lib.pyx", line 912, in pandas.lib.scalar_binop (pandas\lib.c:16177)
    ValueError: cannot include dtype 'M' in a buffer

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Karunyan/PycharmProjects/RECON/criteria/distinct_matched_trades.py", line 18, in <module>
        unionX1 = data[data.cpty_type == 'INTERBRANCH' & (data.settlementDate >= '2017-04-18' | data.settlementDate == '1899-12-30')]
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 929, in wrapper
        na_op(self.values, other),
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 899, in na_op
        x.dtype, type(y).__name__))
    TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [datetime64[ns]] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, bitwise operations like `|`, `&`, and `^` have higher precedence than comparison operations like `<`, `>`, `==`, etc. You need to use parentheses in your expressions to force the correct evaluation order.

For example, if you write `A < B & C < D`, it will be evaluated as `A < (B & C) < D` which will produce an error in the case of Pandas series. You need to explicitly write `(A < B) & (C < D)` to make it work as you expect.

In your case, you can do this:

```
unionX1 = data[(data.cpty_type == 'INTERBRANCH') & ((data.settlementDate >= '2017-04-18') | (data.settlementDate == '2017-04-18'))]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose multiple conditions in braces due to operator precedence and use the bitwise and (`&`) and or (`|`) operators:

```
unionX1 = data[(data.cpty_type == 'INTERBRANCH') & 
               ((data.settlementDate >='2017-04-18') | (data.settlementDate =='2017-04-18'))]
```

Comment: Thanks! I was scratching my head for a while on this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sidestep the operator precedence oddity, you can use `numpy`'s `logical_or` and `logical_and` functions.

```
unionX1 = data[logical_and(
    data.cpty_type == 'INTERBRANCH',
    np.logical_or(
        data.settlementDate >= '2017-04-18',
        data.settlementDate == '2017-04-18'
    )
)]
```

The grouping is explicit, so you get the behavior you intend without having to remember the precedence of binary operators.

Comment: You might want to try this out-- `and` and `or` won't work with Series. :-)